Solar panel cut off with MOSFET
I'm working on a weather station project where I have a small 6 V (max 7 V) solar panel connected to the Lx-LCBST Li-Ion charging (TP4056) circuit, I would like to be able to cut off the solar panel using GPIO from ESP32 when it gets the temp reading around 0°C, the temperature reading circuit is a separate part and its working correctly,
I came up with a simple circuit like this using P-channel MOSFET and would like to get some feedback on that, or maybe should I switch to the BJT? (The max charging current from solar panel so far I detected was around 500 mA).


The S and D labels on your MOSFET don’t match the symbol.

THANKS !! I've just noticed that, picture updated now

You need additional circuitry to turn off your P-FET. A small signal N-FET, a resistor to your P-FET gate and a pull-up on the same to your 7 V would do the trick.

What do you think about the diode in the MOSFET's symbol?

The body diode of your MOSFET will still pass the solar panel current into the charger, minus its forward voltage drop.
Since the voltage being controlled is above the positive supply rail of the MCU, the easiest and simplest implementation for you would be using an N-channel MOSFETs on the negative side, as shown in my schematic below.
This assumes that the charger IC prevents the current from the Li-Ion cell going back through the solar panel, because you will still have that problem above 0°C when the MCU is keeping this MOSFET on at night, unless you program it otherwise.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thanks for the circuit, so after building a circuit using AO3413 n-channel mosfets the behaviour is as follow:

Thanks for the circuit, so after building this circuit using two AO3413 n-channel mosfets and simulating the MCU GPIO state by using the 4V output from the regulator (not the battery itself)
with the gate resistor (1k) it does nothing simply conducting all the time,
Without the gate resistor when the Gates ar shorted to 4V output is goes wild smoking the 1M resistor (I assume its simply working as a  load)
Any ideas why would that be ?

I don’t understand the purpose of using 2 FETs here.

@SteKulov  Good question. This can be done with only the M2 MOSFET in the schematic. The purpose is to block current in both directions, so that neither the solar panel is charging when MOSFET is off, nor is the battery discharging into the panel (very low current, but still there and might affect both the panel and battery life), in case the charging IC doesn't block reverse current into the panel.

@MarcinPluta I don't know where and how have you simulated it, but that should definitely not be happening - there is NO WAY a 1MΩ resistor would burn, especially at such low voltages, so you are definitely doing something wrong. Try "simulate this circuit" under my schematic, then click on the switch to change its state between OPEN and CLOSED, and observe the currents and voltages. It should give you a good idea about what is happening. If your charger IC prevents reverse current into the solar panel, you can do without the M1 MOSFET.

I would think you would want to keep M1 instead of M2.

@SteKulov He wants to disconnect the panel when temperature falls to 0°C and below, to prevent charging the battery as it doesn't accept charge at freezing temperatures. His MCU will monitor the temperature and send the LOW signal to turn it off. If you use M1 alone, the current from the solar panel would not be cut off.

@EdinFifić  I think your model of the MCU pin is what's causing confusion here.  An MCU GPIO normally doesn't switch from 3.3V to high-Z.  It switches from 3.3V and 0V.  If you alter your model to that and re-simulate your circuit you will see it does not work as intended, either with both FETs or removing one of them.

I think the solution proposed by winny is the best approach here.  You already have the P-channel MOSFET, you just have it backwards and need to flip it horizontally such that the source terminal is connected to the solar panel.  You need an additional small-signal N-channel MOSFET to control the other one via the ESP32.  The P-channel MOSFET needs a pullup resistor to its gate when the N-channel is off.  You can optionally add a pulldown resistor to the gate the N-channel, depending on if you need defined behavior when the ESP32 is either off or is in a state where its GPIOs are not yet configured.  You can probably also increase the resistor magnitudes to 100K to save on power losses.  Here's an MSPaint edit of your schematic which illustrates this.

This solution assumes the LX-LCBST cannot leak current from the IN+ pin and back to the solar panel.  If that's a possibility and you don't want that to happen, you can add a 2nd P-channel MOSFET in series to the first one with its source terminals connected together and gate terminals connected together.  Then the body diodes point counter to each other.  The downside to this is you incur an additional Rds(on) penalty from the additional series MOSFET.

It's almost what I need except:
-most of the time i want to keep pin LOW and set it high when temp < 0C to avoid extra power consumption, i think the pull down here can be avoided in my case to save another few uA during sleep mode when there is sun and temp is < 0,
-for the moment i come up with a workaround by using KSD-01 NO 0C thermostat, but that is neither precise or allows control so will try the circuit above ( I assume that if i want to achieve the mentioned behaviour i would not need the N channel and instead i will add 10K current limiting resistor on the line with GPIO ?

@MarcinPluta  No, you need the N-channel MOSFET to properly interface with the P-channel MOSFET.  P-channel turns on when gate is around 1V (or more) lower than source.  If your GPIO is connected directly (as you suggest) and it's set to 3.3V (high), then 7V-3.3V=3.7V so P-channel will be ON.  If GPIO is set to 0V (low), then 7V-0V=7V so P-channel will be ON.  So in both cases P-channel will be ON.  You need the N-channel MOSFET to fix this.

@MarcinPluta  If you require the inverted logic and can't do it in the software, then you can add a 2nd N-channel stage similar to what I show here:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/726764/254890  You can probably increase the resistor values even further to reduce power consumption.
